# Does iTunes Connect offer API for managing external testers from tools?

Tags: app-store-connect

iTunes Connect provides a browser-based UI for adding and removing external testers for apps that are in beta test, using Apple's new version of Test Flight.

Is there a way to access this functionality without using the web UI -- for instance, with a command line tool?

It seems like Apple doesn't provide an *official* API for accessing iTunes Connect programmatically. But a little googling suggests that iTunes Connect is an AngularJS app that talks to a JSON API. Are there any open source projects or working code snippets that show how to use the API?

I am specifically interested in *managing external testers*, not automating the upload of builds to iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 2):

For everything non-sales related, you might want to check out the unoffical documentation of the iTunes Connect JSON API: https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs

please read also :
There's no API for iTunes connect, the only way you can access the information is through the web or with a program that scrapes the web pages. If you want to create something in Objective-C, download AppSales from github, it's an iPhone app which downloads financial reports from ITC (or maybe itts). You can download it and install it on your iPhone if you have an Apple developer account. You can look through their code and see how they scrape the daily and weekly reports (hint: it's ugly).

http://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile

Note that if you try to create an iPhone app to do this, Apple will reject it. It breaks the rule about "No public API". Other people have tried this and been rejected.

If you're just looking for software to do this on your computer, I'd highly recommend AppViz

http://www.ideaswarm.com/products/appviz/

Here's a nice post which compares these and more apps:

http://www.markj.net/sales-stats-tools-for-iphone-apps/

Comment: So the fastlalne api docs show one GET method for returning a list of all testers who can access a build. I guess that's the best there is at the moment.

Comment: "There's no API for iTunes connect"

this is actually incorrect, the iTunes Connect front-end makes use of the WebObject based back-end. I added my reply with a documentation of the needed API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has published APIs for app store connect. By using these APIs you can perform TestFlight related operations like add/delete testers or submit build for review etc. You can find more details here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/testflight

Answer (score 0):

There are some ruby gems used for interfacing with the ***iTMSTransporter***.

iTMSTransporter is the base external tool for the ***iTunesConnect api***.

Here are the ruby gems

[FastLane](https://github.com/KrauseFx/fastlane)

[Deliver](https://github.com/krausefx/deliver)

*fastlane* and *deliver* make it easier.

These gems are useful and can also upload metadata, and images etc.

> iTMSTransporter -help [command]

Hope this would be helpful

Comment: Seems like these don't help with managing external testers, alas.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 more tools powered by the fastlane toolchain:
- Pilot: The best way to manage your TestFlight testers and builds from your terminal
- Boarding (Instantly create a simple signup page for TestFlight beta testers)

Fastlane can be found here: https://github.com/KrauseFx/fastlane