# Get App Version install using testflight

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, testflight

I can easily get Version of my app in appstore with  below API of apple:-

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.app.bundleid&country=in

Also i can check if app is install from testflight or appstore with below code :-

```
if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"embedded" ofType:@"mobileprovision"]) {
    // TestFlight
} else {
    // App Store (and Apple reviewers too)
}
```

My question is that , how to get version of my app install by testflight.
For eg: My release appstore version in 1.0.1 while i have testflight upload version is 1.0.10, i need to check testflight uploaded app version.

here is my code to check version from appstore

```
-(void)checkIsAppUpdated
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.app.bundleid&country=in";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if (!error)
    {

        //The response is in data
        //NSLog(@"Success: %@", stringReply);
        NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        float appStoreTestflightVersion=[[[[dictResponse objectForKey:@"results"] firstObject] objectForKey:@"version"] floatValue];

        NSLog(@"app stroe version=%f",appStoreTestflightVersion);

        NSString *strLocalVersion=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
        float localAppVersion=[strLocalVersion floatValue];
        if (localAppVersion!=appStoreTestflightVersion)
        {

            //delete database here and then create it again


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you can get the short version string like this : `Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"]`Is this what you need ?

Comment: i need to check last version in testflight and then compair with new version, i use CFBundleShortVersionString for getting new version

Comment: Let me see if I understood. You check if the user has a TestFlight version or an app store version.So in your, if else, the value CFBundleShortVersionString can be different no?

Comment: There is no such api for test-flight builds

Comment: @AliABBAS if (localAppVersion!=appStoreTestflightVersion)
        {

            //delete database here and then create it again


        }

Comment: @iphonemaclover Please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780016/does-itunes-connect-offer-api-for-managing-external-testers-from-tools#answer-29975571 
Let me know if it helps